# Subliem text3 AutoFileName: How to change it, that it will add width and heigth attributes in Sublieme text 3

Tags: height, width, sublime-text-plugin, package-control

A year ago I had a snippet that adds the attributes width and height when I inserted a IMG.

Do you know that snippet? Or is there a way to make it?

Example:

[image: You get normally this]

But I want this to be the result:

[image: When you press enter that the width and height are already there]

Comment: It's not mentioned on the blurb page, but AutoFileName does this: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AutoFileName

Comment: @OdatNurd Well I have that snippet but it doesn't add the height and width

Comment: @OdatNurd The AutoFileName it has that function in Sublieme text2 but it is enabled in Sublieme text 3 and When I try to overwrite it with the user preference it doesn't change

Comment: Hmm, indeed. There seems to be an issue logged that indicates it's broken for a lot of people. Possibly it's abandoned now? I don't use that particular package myself. Possibly emmet can do this as well though: http://docs.emmet.io/actions/update-image-size/